# inheritance in my sdl c++ pong game

Tags: c++, inheritance

So I am trying to implement a pong game using sdl but with classes and inheritance.

So I plan to have a base Puck class which defines my paddle. PlayerPuck and EnemyPuck will inherit this base class. The base Puck class handles all the initializations and drawing of the base paddle. From this I am trying to derive a subclass to add extra things on my playerPaddle like checking collisions and bounds etc. But when I try to create objects polymorphically in my main class, it throws me tons of errors.

Here is my Base Puck Header file

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>

class Puck{
private:
    SDL_Rect puckPaddle;
public:
    Puck();
    Puck(int x,int y,int width,int height);
    int getX();
    int getY();
    int getHeight();
    int getWidth();
    SDL_Rect* getPaddleRect();
    void setX(int x);
    void setY(int y);
    void setHeight(int height);
    void setWidth(int width);

    void Render();  // should be virtual, leave it for now
    void Update();  // should be virtual, leave it for now
};
```

This is just my header file. I have done the implementation in the cpp file already and it works fine.

Now the problem is in my PlayerPuck which I have derived from Puck as follows

```
#include "Puck.h"

class PlayerPuck : public Puck {
public:
    PlayerPuck();
    PlayerPuck(int x, int y, int width,int height);
    void UpdatePosition();
    void CheckBounds();
};
```

In my main function when I do the following it gives me error like

> C2504: 'Puck' base class undefined
>
> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'PlayerPuck *' to 'Puck *'

```
 #include "Ball.h"
    #include "Puck.h"
    #include "PlayerPuck.h"

    Puck* p;

    void Initialize(){

        if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1)
            running = false;
        TTF_Init();
        p = new PlayerPuck(50,150,200,100);
    }
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: Might be related to compiling/linking stage. How do you compile this? Are you sure that yo compile Puck.cpp or link Puck.o to PlayerPuck.cpp?

Comment: Might be that you're including `"Puck.h"` twice in the main file as it gets included through `"PlayerPuck.h"`. You should use [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in the header files.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by just adding "PlayerPuck.h" header file and removing the "Puck.h" as there were two same headers in my main function

Now, I am getting linker errors if I try calling virtual functions

in my base Puck class I have defined a virtual function Test()

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>

    class Puck{
    private:
        SDL_Rect puckPaddle;
    public:
        Puck();
        Puck(int x,int y,int width,int height);
        int getX();
        int getY();
        int getHeight();
        int getWidth();
        SDL_Rect* getPaddleRect();
        void setX(int x);
        void setY(int y);
        void setHeight(int height);
        void setWidth(int width);

        **virtual void Test();**   --> here
    };
```

And I have called it in my derived playerPuck class

```
#include "Puck.h"

class PlayerPuck : public Puck {
public:
    PlayerPuck();
    PlayerPuck(int x, int y, int width,int height);
    void UpdatePosition();
    void CheckBounds();
    **void Test();**  --> here
};
```

When I create my playerPuck obj in main and try calling that function as below it throws me 
LNK2001 - unresolved external symbol error

```
#include "Ball.h"
#include "PlayerPuck.h"

PlayerPuck* playerPuck;

playerPuck = new PlayerPuck(50,200,20,100);

void Update(){
    //playerPuck->UpdatePosition();
    playerPuck->Test();
}
```